# Unary operator expected error in while loop execution in shell scripting(UNIX)

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

I wrote a code to print

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

using while loop in shell script. 
But error of expr: syntax error

```
scriptprog3.sh: line 3: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

is showing. Please help out. Here is the code

```
a=5
while [ $a -gt 0 ]
do
 echo $a
 a=` expr $a -1 `
done
```

Comment: Use double parens for arithmetics

Comment: Although I would suggest using double parens, for the sake of learning, the offending line is `$a -1`. It should be `$a - 1`. `expr` expects 3 parameters, the operand, the operator and another operand. So you should end up with `expr $a - 1` instead of `expr $a -1`.

Comment: thanks mate.. Worked out

Comment: Do you not get `expr: syntax error` (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you actually may want:

```
$ a=5
$ while (( a > 0 ));do echo $a ; (( a-- ));done
5
4
3
2
1
```

`(( code ))` makes the math over the `a` var without returning any value back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I was executing the following code and it gave me the "[: -lt: unary operator expected"
error.

```
#while
i = 10
echo "This is a while loop"
while [ $i -lt 15 ]
do
        echo $i
        i=$[ $i+1 ]
done
```

The problem was using while loop as `while [ $i -lt 15 ]` like this,
so I changed it to
`while [[ $i -lt 15 ]]` and it worked (notice the double parentheses).

Below is the working example.

```
#while
i = 10
echo "This is a while loop"
while [[ $i -lt 15 ]]
do
        echo $i
        i=$[ $i+1 ]
done
```